# NodeJS setInterval error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Going through a tutorial in a NodeJS book. It gives me this code for trying out setInterval:

```js
var x = 0,
    y = 0,
    z = 0;

function displayValues() {
    console.log("X=%d; Y=%d; Z=%d", x, y, z);
}

function updateX() {
    x += 1;
}

function updateY() {
    y += 1;
}

function updateZ() {
    z += 1;
    displayValues();
}

setInterval(updateX, 500);
setInterval(updateY, 1000);
setInterval(updateZ, 2000);
```

And it works just like it's supposed to. So then I try out making my own much simpler version:

```js
var x = 0;

function incrementX() {
    x++;
    console.log(x);
}

setInterval(incrementX(), 1000);
```

and it doesn't work. It displays 1 after one second, then gives me this error message:

```js
timers.js:265
    callback.apply(this, args);
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Can anyone explain to me why the first snippet works, but the second one doesn't?

Comment: You have the wrong callback name. Remove "()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use braces `()`

```
setInterval(incrementX, 1000);
```

When you pass `incrementX()`, you are actually passing the result returned by `incrementX()` and not the function. `incrementX` is the function which is what `setInterval` expects.

Comment: Wow. It works. Would you mind explaining why that works? I guess I still just don't understand the difference between using parentheses and not using them.

Comment: setInterval is looking for a function in its first parameter and you are not returning a function from incrementX.

Comment: If you read the documenation [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) accept a `function` as parameter.

Comment: `incrementX()` actually calls and executes the function, whereas `incrementX` is a reference to the function, which is what `setInterval` requires.